# Use Python to query an Azure SQL database with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

I only see there is a username&&password credential to allow me to connect to Azure SQL database right now.

Is a way to let me connect to SQL database with Azure AD credential? e.g I want to use device_code_credentials

```
device_code_credentials = DeviceCodeCredential(client_id, tenant_id=tenant_id, authority=authority_host_uri)
```

I can call blob service client with this credential and wondering is there a simple way in Python SDK to connect to Azure SQL database.

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
   account_url=self.url,
   credential=self.credential
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using Azure AD authentication to connect to Azure SQL database.

Get the AD Active Directory password authentication on Portal:
[image]

Python code example:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'your_server.database.windows.net'
database = 'your_database'
username = 'your_username'
password = 'your_password'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
Authentication='ActiveDirectoryPassword'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER='+driver+
    ';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+
    ';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+
    ';UID='+username+
    ';PWD='+ password+
    ';Authentication='+Authentication)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to save plain text password inside the source code. Could I use any other approach?

Comment: @Jonas Yes, you can follow the this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted) to  create the Always Encrypted SQL connection string, then using the encrypted connection string to connect to the Azure SQL database. This will help you protect the password.

Comment: @Jonas You Here's the another tutorial [Encrypting passwords for use with Python and SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5173/encrypting-passwords-for-use-with-python-and-sql-server/).

Comment: This is very helpful, but I am getting an error saying I must use multi-factor authentication to connect to the database. Is it still possible to connect?

Comment: @Irina No, some thing changed now. Azure now suggest  us use AD MFA authentication to connect SQL database. For some region, AD password is not work now.