# Error: ('CE267', '[CE267] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error 12029 opening URL

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, pyodbc

Trying to connect Azure SQL server database which I am able to connect from my local machine through SSMS , getting below error while trying to connect using PYODBC

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Authentication='+ auth)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

> Error: ('CE267', '[CE267] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error 12029 opening URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while trying to connect to sql server with python using pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209295/error-while-trying-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-python-using-pyodbc)

Comment: You can refer to [Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Use Python to query an Azure SQL database with Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570127/use-python-to-query-an-azure-sql-database-with-azure-ad)

Comment: Be aware that ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server [has breaking changes](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) to some of the defaults to require encrypted connections and valid server certificates. But your error message suggests that the connection string is broken is broken in other ways.

Comment: `PORT=1433;` isn't a valid [Connection String Keyword and Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute). 1433 is the default port, but if you need to include a custom port in your connection string it's normally done with `SERVER=serverNameOrIpAddress,yourPortNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @AlwaysLearning, Driver 18 has breaking changes, one of which is reversing the default encryption setting from "no" to "yes".

You might try adding to your conn. string: "Encrypt=no;"

This worked for me.